# Dynamic text colour fill css

Tags: html, css, textcolor

I am trying to fill in text with colour from left to right as with the following [codepen](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/WoXJXQ).

This is causing a problem with the following css:

```
@keyframes stripes {
    to {
        width: 32px;
    }
}
```

Words which are longer than 32px, aren't being completely filled in and stop by 32px. If I increase this width, short words (e.g. dog) will be filled in at a fast pace.

I would like to have **all** words filled-in in **2 seconds** (irrespective of the word length)

Anyone has an idea how this can be done please?

Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```css
.tooltiptext {
    position: relative;
    display: inline-block;
}
.tooltiptext:after {
    content: "";
}
.popUpWord {
    color: pink;
    white-space: nowrap;
}
.popUpWordBlack {
    color: black;
}
.outPop {
    margin: auto;
    background: none;
    overflow: hidden;
    display: block;
    position: absolute;
    animation-play-state: unset;
    left: 0;
    top: 0;
    width:0;
}
.outPopBlack:hover + .outPop,
.outPop:hover {
    animation: stripes 2s linear 1 forwards;
}
.outPopBlack {
    display: block;
    position: relative;
    z-index: 0;
}
@keyframes stripes {
    to {
        width: 100%;
    }
}
```

```html
<span class="tooltiptext"> 
  <span class="outPopBlack">
    <span class="popUpWordBlack">hello World</span>
  </span>  
  <span class="outPop">
    <span class="popUpWord">hello World</span>
  </span>
</span>
```

if you don't have to use multiple lines you can use this method ,

add "display: inline-block;" to tooltiptext

add white-space: nowrap; to .popUpWord,

change style of .outPop to 
    margin: auto;
    background: none;
    overflow: hidden;
    display: block;
    position: absolute;
    animation-play-state: unset;
    left: 0;
    top: 0;
    width:0;

also you can use these method in less code

```css
.text {
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
  z-index: 0;
}

.text:after {
  content: "HEllo World";
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 1;
  color: red;
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
  width: 0;
  white-space: nowrap;
  overflow: hidden;
  transition: 500ms linear all;
}

.text:hover:after {
  width: 100%;
}

.text1 {
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
  z-index: 0;
}

.text1>.dup {
  content: "HEllo World";
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 1;
  color: red;
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
  width: 0;
  white-space: nowrap;
  overflow: hidden;
  transition: 500ms linear all;
}

.text1:hover>.dup {
  width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<div class="text">
  HEllo World
</div>
<br>
<br>
<div class="text1">
  HEllo World
  <span class="dup">HEllo World</span>
</div>
```

Comment: Great thanks! And is there a way I can display coloured text from left to right without having two overlapping spans? It's complicating things when trying to find elements in the DOM

Comment: Yes .. i just added code in my answer.. pls refer it

Comment: I'm seeing the code. In your example it works because you specified overlaying text in the 'content' property in css. How can this be done if you use different phrases?

Comment: I think I found the solution. Will post it soon